# networkmanager-strongswan vpn - routing specific ip through VPN

Tags: linux-mint, networkmanager, vpn, iproute, strongswan

I'm trying to setting a VPN on Linux Mint 19.2.

I'm using the *network-manager-strongswan* so I added this file named *VPN* under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

```
[connection]
id=VPN
uuid=be1d4fd1-bbaa-4aa9-9fdc-e293bf16fe67
type=vpn
autoconnect=false
permissions=
timestamp=1582680217

[vpn]
address=vpn********.it
certificate=
encap=yes
ipcomp=no
method=eap
password-flags=0
proposal=no
user=user
virtual=yes
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.strongswan

[vpn-secrets]
password=password

[ipv4]
dns-search=
ignore-auto-dns=true
ignore-auto-routes=true
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
ip6-privacy=0
method=ignore
```

The connection is fine, I can access using ssh on the private network. The big issue is that after the connection I can't surf the internet, connecting to the vpn lock all other addresses.
I added the `ignore-auto-routes` flag in the config so why my connection is locked?

---

**ip a** output*

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:3c:de:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet yy.16.209.132/24 brd yy.16.209.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute ens33
       valid_lft 1656sec preferred_lft 1656sec
    inet yy.26.199.18/32 scope global ens33
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::216e:bcc0:3b4f:44b2/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

**route -n** output

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         yy.16.209.2    0.0.0.0         UG    20100  0        0 ens33
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ens33
yy.16.209.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens33
yy.26.199.18   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    50     0        0 ens33
yy.26.199.18   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens33
```

---

**ip xfrm policy** output **NO VPN**

```
src yy.16.209.0/24 dst yy.16.209.0/24 
    dir fwd priority 175423 
src yy.16.209.0/24 dst yy.16.209.0/24 
    dir in priority 175423 
src yy.16.209.0/24 dst yy.16.209.0/24 
    dir out priority 175423 
src 169.254.0.0/16 dst 169.254.0.0/16 
    dir fwd priority 183615 
src 169.254.0.0/16 dst 169.254.0.0/16 
    dir in priority 183615 
src 169.254.0.0/16 dst 169.254.0.0/16 
    dir out priority 183615 
src fe80::/64 dst fe80::/64 
    dir fwd priority 134463 
src fe80::/64 dst fe80::/64 
    dir in priority 134463 
src fe80::/64 dst fe80::/64 
    dir out priority 134463 
src yy.26.199.18/32 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    dir out priority 383615 
    tmpl src yy.16.209.132 dst xx.xx.124.58
        proto esp spi 0xc57cfb3f reqid 7 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst yy.26.199.18/32 
    dir fwd priority 383615 
    tmpl src xx.xx.124.58 dst yy.16.209.132
        proto esp reqid 7 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst yy.26.199.18/32 
    dir in priority 383615 
    tmpl src xx.xx.124.58 dst yy.16.209.132
        proto esp reqid 7 mode tunnel
src ::1/128 dst ::1/128 
    dir fwd priority 68927 
src ::1/128 dst ::1/128 
    dir in priority 68927 
src ::1/128 dst ::1/128 
    dir out priority 68927 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket out priority 0
```

**ip xfrm policy** output **UNDER VPN**

```
src yy.26.199.18/32 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    dir out priority 383615 
    tmpl src yy.16.209.132 dst xx.xx.124.58
        proto esp spi 0xc787ea42 reqid 2 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst yy.26.199.18/32 
    dir fwd priority 383615 
    tmpl src xx.xx.124.58 dst yy.16.209.132
        proto esp reqid 2 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst yy.26.199.18/32 
    dir in priority 383615 
    tmpl src xx.xx.124.58 dst yy.16.209.132
        proto esp reqid 2 mode tunnel
src fe80::/64 dst fe80::/64 
    dir fwd priority 134463 
src fe80::/64 dst fe80::/64 
    dir in priority 134463 
src fe80::/64 dst fe80::/64 
    dir out priority 134463 
src ::1/128 dst ::1/128 
    dir fwd priority 68927 
src ::1/128 dst ::1/128 
    dir in priority 68927 
src ::1/128 dst ::1/128 
    dir out priority 68927 
src yy.16.209.0/24 dst yy.16.209.0/24 
    dir fwd priority 175423 
src yy.16.209.0/24 dst yy.16.209.0/24 
    dir in priority 175423 
src yy.16.209.0/24 dst yy.16.209.0/24 
    dir out priority 175423 
src 169.254.0.0/16 dst 169.254.0.0/16 
    dir fwd priority 183615 
src 169.254.0.0/16 dst 169.254.0.0/16 
    dir in priority 183615 
src 169.254.0.0/16 dst 169.254.0.0/16 
    dir out priority 183615 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket out priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket in priority 0 
src ::/0 dst ::/0 
    socket out priority 0
```

Diffing the outputs I can see this piece is added while the VPN is connected:

```
src yy.26.199.18/32 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    dir out priority 383615 
    tmpl src yy.16.209.132 dst xx.xx.124.58
        proto esp spi 0xc787ea42 reqid 2 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst yy.26.199.18/32 
    dir fwd priority 383615 
    tmpl src xx.xx.124.58 dst yy.16.209.132
        proto esp reqid 2 mode tunnel
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst yy.26.199.18/32 
    dir in priority 383615 
    tmpl src xx.xx.124.58 dst yy.16.209.132
        proto esp reqid 2 mode tunnel
```

---

I tried a lot of things but with no luck.

- tried to increase the `Metric` for yy.26.199.18 to 1050 and 1100.
- `route del default` && `ip route add default via yy.26.199.18 dev ens33`
- Tried to delete the route entries yy.26.199.18 but nothing changes

and a lot of others stupid stuff.

So I want to use my connection for the "normal internet" while routing specific addresses through VPN.
It is possible?

Comment: StrongSwan uses policy based routing: add the output of `ip xfrm policy`. [Route-based routing](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/RouteBasedVPN) is also possible. I am not sure whether the [libcharon-nm](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/NetworkManager) can use some advances configuration.

Comment: ip xfrm policy output added in the last edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Strongswan** uses policy routing, which are configured through `xfrm` policies:

1. the `dir out` policy says what to do with packets from `172.26.199.18/32` to `0.0.0.0/0`: they need to be encrypted and sent through the VPN tunnel.
2. the `dir in` and `dir fwd` policies says what to do when an encrypted packet comes in. If, after decryption, a packet from `0.0.0.0/0` to `172.26.199.18/32` didn't come from the specified tunnel, it is dropped. Plaintext packets are not subject to this.

In order to restrict the usage of the VPN network you have three solutions:

1. The networks that appear in these rules are negotiated between your IKE server and the remote one. The NetworkManager plugin always proposes a tunnel between `your_ip/32` and `0.0.0.0/0`. If the remote server proposes `0.0.0.0/0` and `10.0.0.0/8` the resulting connection will be: between `your_ip/32` and `10.0.0.0/8`. So you need to ask the administrator of the remote endpoint to properly configure his IKE daemon.
2. You can renounce using NetworkManager for the VPN tunnel, install **charon-systemd** and create a simple configuration file (e.g. `/etc/swanctl/conf.d/my_vpn.conf`):

   ```
   connections {
       my_vpn {
           version = 2
           local_addrs=%any
           remote_addrs=vpn********.it
           local {
               auth = eap
               eap_id = your_username
           }
           remote {
               auth = pubkey
               id = server_name
           }
           children {
               my_tunnel {
                   #local_ts = dynamic
                   remote_ts = remote_network
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   reload the daemon (`systemctl reload strongswan-swanctl`) and run:

   ```
   swanctl --initiate --ike my_vpn --child my_tunnel
   ```
3. Add your own policies, with a `priority` value smaller than the automatically installed on, which will allow unencrypted traffic, e.g.:

   ```
   ip xfrm policy add src your_ip/32 dst 192.0.2.0/24 \
       dir out priority 1000
   ip xfrm policy add src 192.0.2.0/24 dst your_ip/32 \
       dir in priority 1000
   ```

   which will allow plaintext traffic to `192.0.2.0/24`.

Comment: I tried the latest of the solutions you proposed (it seems to be the simpler). But I can't make it works. Any help?

Comment: The third solution requires you to add all prefixes that you **don't** want to route through the VPN, which can be a lot of rules. Can you update `ip xfrm policy` in your question? I would rank the first solution as the best: if you are connecting to your work network, your admin does not want you to browse the Internet from the VPN either.

Comment: Ok it works really well. Sorry I misunderstood your answer. Anyway it is working now... and yes my admin is locking all except internal network. Switching between vpn and normal connection is a big pain. I'll make a script to add the main sites to the policies or something of more sophisticated then I will be ok. Thanks.I'll assign to you the reward, for now is locked your answers are too fast!

Comment: I wrote a daemon that adds at runtime searched addresses to policies getting it from a tcpdump in background. I wrote it on a virtual machine and works really fine. I can surf the web without problems. To add policies I use `ip xfrm policy add src 0.0.0.0/0 dst "$addr"/24 dir out priority 1000` and `ip xfrm policy add src "$addr"/24 dst 0.0.0.0/0 dir in priority 1000`... But when I install the daemon on the host it doesn't work!

Comment: Saying the thruth if I run these 2 commands on the host the new policies doesn't work , they are added to xfrm but the addresses continue to pass through the VPN. I also tried to change 0.0.0.0/0 with my ip and with ip assigned by the VPN. No luck. Some hint?